# Skipping more than one node in Floyd's cycle finding Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, floyd-cycle-finding

Today I was reading Floyd's algorithm of detecting loop in a linked list.
I was just wondering that won't it be better if we skip more than one node, (say 2)
for faster loop detection?

For example:

```
fastptr=fastptr->next->next->next.
```

Note that the side effects will be taken into account while changing `fastptr`.

Comment: If you skip more than 1, you might miss the loop detection at the earliest point.

Comment: @leppie, can you give one such example?

Comment: Even worse, you might not detect the loop at all. Consider a loop with length 6 where the hare is at node 0 when the tortoise is at node 1. If the hare moves three steps for every step of the tortoise, the subsequent tortoise/hare positions are 2/3, 3/0, 4/3, 5/0, 0/3, 1/0, 2/3 ad infinitum and the existence of the loop is never detected.

Comment: ... except that I don't see a way of getting to the necessary initial conditions for such an infinite loop.  Dangit, now I'm going to be awake all night thinking about this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your suggestion still is correct, but it doesn't change the speed of algorithm. If you take a look at tortoise and hare algorithm in [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection#Tortoise_and_hare):

> The key insight in the algorithm is that, for any integers i ≥ μ and k
>   ≥ 0, x<sub>i</sub> = x<sub>i + kλ</sub>, where λ is the length of the
>   loop to be found and μ is start position of loop. In particular,
>   whenever i = kλ ≥ μ, it follows that **x<sub>i</sub> =
>   x<sub>2i</sub>**.

In the bold part, you could also say **x<sub>i</sub> = x<sub>3i</sub>**, or any other coefficient, but key insight is finding the **i**, it's not important with how many jumps you will find it, and order of algorithm, depends to the location of **i**.